# WCF timeout handling

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We are currently developing a software solution which has a client and a number of WCF services that it consumes. The issues we are having is WCF services timing out after a period of inactivity. As far as I understand, there are 2 ways to resolve this:

1. Increase timeouts (as far as I understood, this is generally not recommended. Eg. setting timeout to infinite/weeks is considered bad practice)
2. Periodically ping the WCF services from the Client (I'm not sure that I'm a huge fan of his as it will add redundant, periodic calls)
3. Handle timeout issues and attempt to reconnect (this is slow and requires a lot of manual code)
4. Reliable Sessions - some sources mention that this is the in-built WCF pinging and message reliability mechanism, but other sources mention that this will still time out.

What is the recommended/best way of resolving this issue? Is there any official reading material on this? I could not find all that much info myself

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i can see, you have to use a combination of your stated points.

1. You are right, increasing the timeouts is bad practice and can give you a lot of problems.
2. If you don't want to use Reliable Sessions, then Ping is the only applicable way to hold the connection.
3. You need to handle this things, no matter if a timeout occurs, the connection is lost or a exception is thrown. There are a plenty of possibilities that your connection can fault.
4. Reliable Sessions are a good way not to implement a ping, but technically, it does nearly the same. WCF automatically sends an "I am still here" Request.

The conclusion of this is, that you need point 3 and point 2 or 4. To reduce the manually code for point 3, you can use Proxies or a wrapper around your ServiceClient, that establishes a new connection if the old one is faulted during a request. Point 4 is easy to implement, because you only need some small additions to your binding in your config. And the traffic overhead is not that big. Point 2 is the most expensive way, you need to handle a Thread/Task that only pings the server and the service needs to be extended. But as you stated before, Reliable Sessions can fail, and Pings should bring you on the safe side.

Comment: That sounds about right I guess. Thanks for sharing your opinion :) Have you had much experience with WCF yourself? Did you end up implementing a similar pattern?

Comment: @Ross Yes, we wrote a dynamic duplex service in wcf as base for a couple inhouse projects. My answer reflect all my experience in wcf for the last 3 years. We implemented point 3 and 4, but Reliable Sessions are not that reliable as they should ;) So we implemented Ping and since that, all runs perfect.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks a lot for sharing your experience :)

Comment: I've made some progress one the Simplex service timeouts - things are now not timing out due to increased timeouts & periodic pings and if/when they do, they automatically reconnect if able! The issue that I am having now is handling the same issue from a duplex service point of view. Pretty much, reconnecting from service back to the client channel, which does not seem to be possible as there is no way to store the OperationContext.Current from subscription for later re-connection. Any ideas on this at all? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself what is your WCF endpoint is doing? Is the way you have your command setup the most optimal? 
Perhaps it'd be better to have your endpoint that takes a long time be based on a polling system that allows there to be a quick query instead of waiting on the results of the endpoints actions. 
You should also consider data transfer as a possible issue. Is the amount of data you're transferring back a lot?

To get a more pointed answer, we'd need to know more about the specific endpoint as well as any other responsibilities there are for the service.

Comment: We have a few different WCF services for different purposes. Some are simplex and some are duplex. All of them perform quick operations (a couple of seconds at the most, with majority being much quicker). The problem is that a number of those are used intermittently, so there could be hours between requests to those services, in which we would like to keep them running, to not have to spin them up every time, which would mean delays.

Comment: You shouldn't have issues leaving the two processes running. Have you tried re-establishing connections between the two processes when attempting to invoke a call after a while?

Comment: Accidentally hit 'enter'. 
If you re-establish a connection for each service command, it can make issues with connectivity easier. 
You're programs should have loops that they're running to be able to answer endpoint commands upon request. There shouldn't be a need to start up processes everytime. 
Why are they coming down? If it's due to timeouts, then it's an issue with a command taking too long between the services.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Just to clarify - the processes are running, however the WCF calls result in a "CommunicationObjectFaultedException", which only happens after the a 5-10 minute period of inactivity, so that is why we think it is the WCF timing out (which seems consistent with some of the documentation bits that I have found). We can try to reconnect, however with hundreds of different calls, this will get quite manual and error prone.

Comment: What we were thinking of, is a single change - either to service configuration or by adding a Ping() method for every service and periodically pinging them. The problem is that neither of those seem... great :/

Comment: For example: SomeProxy.DoStuff() // this will be called from the client, on button click, once in a blue moon and that is why I believe the services are timing out :(